# Dockerized nmap shows incorrect OS versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, nmap

I've noticed that when Nmap is dockerized it is yielding incorrect OS results.  I've tried various pre-built docker images as well as one I created myself and they all show the same results.

Here are a few of the pre-built images I've tried:
https://hub.docker.com/r/instrumentisto/nmap
https://hub.docker.com/r/uzyexe/nmap/

I've run the same Nmap command with these images and using my locally installed Nmap version  and here are the results (all images are using Nmap 7.80):

```
$ nmap -sV -O 192.168.1.1

------(locally installed nmap result - correct): 
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6
OS details: Linux 2.6.8 - 2.6.30
Network Distance: 1 hop
Service Info: OS: Linux; Device: broadband router; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

------(all docker image nmap results - incorrect): 
OS CPE: cpe:/h:hp:jetdirect_170x cpe:/h:hp:inkjet_3000
Aggressive OS guesses: HP 170X print server or Inkjet 3000 printer (85%), HP LaserJet 4000 printer (85%), HP LaserJet 4250 printer (85%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).
Service Info: OS: Linux; Device: broadband router; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel
```

What's interesting to me is that the `Service Info` is actually correct across the scans, but nothing else is.

I'm trying to figure out of there is a setting/flag that I'm missing when executing the docker command.  Here's what I've tried:

- Setting the docker network to `host` (no change in result)
- Setting the docker network to `bridge` (no change in result)
- Not setting any `network` setting (no change in result)

I really need to get Nmap working in a docker container because it's integrated into a rails web app that I'm building utilizing the `ruby-nmap` gem.

Thanks!

Comment: This line: *"No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal)."*. **Timing** is an important part of OS detection so my hunch would be on network latency caused by Docker. I am not knowledgeable about Docker but it seems to me that a transparent bridge is the solution that would interfere the less with results. Ref: [The Impact of Container Virtualization on Network Performance of IoT Devices](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/misy/2018/9570506/). PS you can try the `-A` option which is more aggressive.

Comment: @Anonymous I agree with you.  I did some more testing and it seems that this 'issue' is also only related to the docker container running on a Mac.  It worked fine on a Linux box... not sure about Windows.